# Resistance in parallel with MOSFETs

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

[image: Normal ON/OFF circuit]

Here I have a P-channel transistor (Q1) and two N-channel transistors (Q2 and Q3). I would like to know more about the resistors (R1 and R2) in parallel with these MOSFETs.

Are these resistors pull-up and pull-down resistors? Or do they have something to do with the value of the tension of VGS of these MOSFETs, to allow the MOSFETs to act as a switch?

Comment: They are MOSFETs and not PNP or NPN. Clean your question up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasnt so sure about them and i guessed that i placed the wrong information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are pullup/pulldown resistors than ensure the gates take the correct voltage in the absence of any input.

The gate of a MOSFET is basically a capacitor. Pressing the ON button in this schematic charges the gate of Q3 with respect to the source, turning it on. When the button is released, the gate discharges through R3 and turns Q3 off again. Without R3, the gate would simply stay charged and Q3 would stay turned on.

The same happens with Q1 and R1: turning on either Q2 or Q3 turns on Q1, and R1 ensures that when Q2 and Q3 are both turned off that Q1 turns off too.

Assuming the gates are driven with a low enough impedance, the resistors have no effect on the value of Vgs.

Answer (score 2):

Yea. They make sure that the gate input of mosfet/transistor is at valid logic level. Here R2 is pulls down the gate of Q2--> '0' and R1 Pulls up the gate of Q1 ---> '1'. Without these, the inputs are said to be 'floating'. Floating inputs may pick noise and leads to unpredictable transitions at the output.

Answer (score 1):

They're essentially pull ups/downs. They keep the gate at a fixed potential rather than floating so charge does not accumulate and incorrectly turn on the MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

Si2365EDS is a very low Ron logic level PFET switch , Q1.

PB2 is a momentary pushbutton high to turn on both Q3 and Q1.
Then PB0 can be driven high to latch ON Q1 as logical NOR.

The R values can be high since the switch off time is not important. T=R*Ciss